# why as.numeric function in R doesn't work properly?

Tags: r, character, numeric

I have these two characters and the "as.numeric" function doesn't work same for them. Can anyone help me why this is happening?

> options(digits=22)
>
> a="27"
>
> as.numeric(a)

[1] 27.00000000000000000000

> a="193381411288395777"
>
> as.numeric(a)

[1] 193381411288395776.0000

It can be seen that in the second case the last digit is not "7" and it is "6". Basically the "as.numeric" function decreases 1 unit from the number in the second case.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn about the limits of representation of exact numbers.  R can tell you what it has:

```
R> .Machine
$double.eps
[1] 2.22045e-16

$double.neg.eps
[1] 1.11022e-16

$double.xmin
[1] 2.22507e-308

$double.xmax
[1] 1.79769e+308

$double.base
[1] 2

$double.digits
[1] 53

$double.rounding
[1] 5

$double.guard
[1] 0

$double.ulp.digits
[1] -52

$double.neg.ulp.digits
[1] -53

$double.exponent
[1] 11

$double.min.exp
[1] -1022

$double.max.exp
[1] 1024

$integer.max
[1] 2147483647

$sizeof.long
[1] 8

$sizeof.longlong
[1] 8

$sizeof.longdouble
[1] 16

$sizeof.pointer
[1] 8

R>
```

Comment: There are several packages which will allow you to do what you want.  int64, gmp, ..., I know there are others but those are the ones I know off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `int64` package:

```
library(int64)
> as.int64("193381411288395777")
[1] 193381411288395777
```

Comment: The int64 package lets you display those numbers, but since the number is stored as a size-2 list, you can't do much analysis with them. I'd say you're best off using numeric and taking the hit on precision. Depends on what you need to do though!

Comment: Thanks, but I need to get this number because as numeric. Because it is an input to another function and I need the whole number.