# as.numeric() removes decimal places in R, how to change?

Tags: r

I have what I hope is a simple question about as.numeric().  I have a bunch of data with numbers written as characters.  I want them to be numeric, but as.numeric() takes away decimal spots.  For example:

```
y <- as.character("0.912345678")
as.numeric(y)
0.9123457
```

Thank you :)

Comment: options(digits = 9)

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I'm too lazy to find a suitable question to link it to right now.

Comment: @Dason possibly this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287616/controlling-digits-in-r) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11568385/why-as-numeric-function-in-r-doesnt-work-properly)? I'm not sure the answers are similar enough so I didn't flag the question.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

R is basically following some basic configuration settings for printing the number of required digits. You can change this with the `digits` option as follows:

```
> options(digits=9)
> y <- as.character("0.912345678")
> as.numeric(y)
[1] 0.912345678
```

Small **EDIT** for clarity:
`digits` corresponds to the number of digits to display **in total**, and not just the number of digits after the comma.

For example,

```
> options(digits=9)
> y <- as.character("10.123456789")
> as.numeric(y)
[1] 10.1234568
```

In your example above the leading zero before the comma is not counted, this is why 9 digits was enough to display the complete number.

Answer (score 7):

What's going on is that R is only **displaying** a fixed number of digits.

This [R-help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/as-numeric-is-truncating-td990546.html) post explains what's going on. To quote Peter Dalgaard:

> "There's a difference between an object and the display of an object."

With your example,

```
y2 = as.numeric(y)
print(y2)
# [1] 0.9123457
```

but subtract 0.9 to see

```
y2 - 0.9
# [1] 0.01234568
```

**Updated** based upon the comment by @Khashaa
To change your display use

```
options(digits = 9)
y2
# [1] 0.912345678
```