# Convert scientific notation to numeric, preserving decimals

Tags: r, format, number-formatting

For some reason, when I convert a character column of numbers in scientific notation, the decimals aren't preserved.

```
> str(output)
'data.frame':   213950 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ColA    : chr  ".3370E+03" ".3375E+03" ".3380E+03" ".3385E+03" ...
 $ ColB    : chr  ".4942E+00" ".5295E+00" ".5682E+00" ".6091E+00" ...

> output$ColA = as.numeric(output$ColA)

> str(output)
'data.frame':   213950 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ColA    : num  337 338 338 338 339 ...
 $ ColB    : chr  ".4942E+00" ".5295E+00" ".5682E+00" ".6091E+00" ...
```

I would expect it to read:

```
$ ColA    : num  337 337.5 338 338.5 ...
```

I tried the solution from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880210/as-numeric-removes-decimal-places-in-r-how-to-change), but no luck:

```
> options(digits=9)
> str(output)
'data.frame':   213950 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ColA      : num  337 338 338 338 339 ...
 $ ColB      : chr  ".4942E+00" ".5295E+00" ".5682E+00" ".6091E+00" ...
```

What's going on?

Comment: `options(scipen = 999)` maybe?

Comment: `str()` isn't going to show all the digits. Look at the column on it's own.

Comment: @MrFlick, didn't realize that, thanks for the heads up! For what it's worth, I did try looking at the individual column with `head$ColA` and it was still not displaying decimals before I applied Masoud's `options()` fix.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can turn off scientific notation for numbers using the option below;

```
options(scipen = 999)
```

That would make all the numbers to appear as decimals.

---

If you want to revert it back to the default, use

```
options(scipen = 0)
```

See `getOption("scipen")` for more options.