# Remove class in R markdown knit

Tags: r

How can I remove the data types from the HTML output[image]

Comment: easiest way would be to use `as.data.frame(Highestsales)` instead but maybe there are some relevant arguments in `?tibble:::print.tbl`

Comment: it removed the data types  , but the sales value is turned into (3.75e+10) like this not sure whats going on there

Comment: that's scientific notation, you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44725320/2994949) to change the printing format