# Convert UNIX time string to date in R

Tags: r

I have the following UNIX time string:

"1575824800.169"

If you convert this time you will get: 12/08/2019 17:06 
on an online unix converter.

However when trying to convert this in R using the following code:

```
as.POSIXct("1575824800.169", format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', origin = "1970-01-01")
```

I am returned with the value **NA**

i'm struggling to see why the above code does not work - i have looked into different answers on here, but have not found one where the unix time string has 3 digits after the period (dot) in the string. Maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Your theory sounds reasonable - have you tried getting rid of the numbers after the decimal place?

Comment: @SDS0 I did try that - but it still never worked - i am unsure as to why POSIXct does not seem to work with this date. I believe that there is a way to solve this issue - but maybe base R POSIXct() is not the best function to use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a **string** encoding a date (as implied by using the `format` argument of as.POSIXct) but a **number**. If we re-cast the string as a numeric and get rid of the format argument we get the expected result (although we might need to use the `tz` argument to specify a timezone)

```
as.POSIXct(1575824800.169, origin = "1970-01-01")
```

Returns:

```
[1] "2019-12-08 18:06:40 CET"
```

## Edit:

Adding timezone argument

```
as.POSIXct(1575824800.169, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UCT")
```

Returns:

```
[1] "2019-12-08 17:06:40 UTC"
```

## Edit 2:

Regarding converting the string to numeric with `as.numeric`: As @IceCreamToucan pointed out, it does not matter. Only the "printed" value changes, the internal representation stays the same and therefore the result is still correct

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric("1575824800.169"), origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UCT")
```

Returns the same:

```
[1] "2019-12-08 17:06:40 UTC"
```

Comment: Ah thank you - the issue actually seems to be that when converting from character to numeric - R removes any trailing values after the decimal point - which is why when converting to POSIXct - easily solved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880210/as-numeric-removes-decimal-places-in-r-how-to-change

Comment: I think the problem was that you tried to use the numeric representation of a datetime as if it was a string representation (i.e. "21-12-1999"). The `format` argument works only with the latter while the `origin argument` works only with the former...

Answer (score 0):

The `anytime` package aims to help here with some built-in heuristics.  So *numeric* data in that range is automagically taken as (fractional) seconds since the epoch:

```
R> anytime::anytime(1575824800.169)
[1] "2019-12-08 11:06:40.168 CST"
R>
```

There is also a wrapper for UTC and some other options should you need them:

```
R> anytime::utctime(1575824800.169)
[1] "2019-12-08 17:06:40.168 UTC"
R>
```